# Harmonic sequence recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I'm really getting the hang of recursion (or so I think), but this problem is tripping me up.  I'm trying to return 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n, but no matter what I try the method returns 1.0. I cannot for the life of me figure out what's wrong.

```
public static double harmonic(int n) {
    if(n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return (1 / n) + (1 / harmonic(n - 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked this with a debugger step by step?

Comment: Use doubles in your division calculations, i.e. `(1.0 / n)`.

Comment: Yes, I did. It's difficult for me to follow recursion problems through a debugger, however, as there are so many levels that it's tough to follow what's going on.

Comment: You may also want to protect against the infinite recursion you'll get if a zero or negative number is mistakenly passed for `n`.

Comment: Yeah, I would normally make the base case `if(n <= 1) {`, but this is for an online submission system and for some reason it's only accepting what I currently have.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, for one, you don't want to return `(1 / n) + (1 / harmonic(n - 1))`, but also you need to use `double` arithmetic:

```
public static double harmonic(int n) {
    if(n == 1) {
        return 1.0;
    } else {
        return (1.0 / n) + harmonic(n - 1);
    }
}
```

If you left it as `1 / harmonic` you'd return another function entirely:

> (1 / n) + 1 / ( 1 / (n - 1) + 1 / ( 1 / (n - 2) + 1 / (...) ) )

That is a very confusing function to figure out, btw, but I think (with my 3rd time editing it) I got it right this time.

Comment: That's it! Others suggested using doubles, which was definitely part of the problem, but you also got the correction in the `return` statement. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

You want to use floating point division:

```
public static double harmonic(int n) {
    if(n == 1.0) {
        return 1.0;
    } else {
        return (1.0 / n) + (1.0 / harmonic(n - 1.0));
    }
}
```

That is: `1/2` is `0`; `1/2.0` is `0.5`.

Comment: Ah, that's part of the problem, but I also implemented my formula incorrectly (it should be `return (1.0 / n) + harmonic(n - 1);`. Thank you!

Comment: glad i could help! I only sought to point out why you were getting '0', not anything beyond that point. Brian went the extra mile

Answer (score 2):

Thats because integer division gives integer result.

So, `1/2 == 0`

You can use rather use `floating-point` division like this: -

```
if(n == 1.0) {
    return 1.0;
} else {
    return (1.0 / n) + harmonic(n - 1); // Should be `harmonic(n - 1)`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use doubles.  Right now, you're doing `1 / n`, both of which are integers.  Change it to:

```
return (1.0 / n) + (1.0 / harmonic(n - 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use doubles in your division calculations.  Currently, everything is cast to ints, losing any floating-point precision you would normally expect.

```
public static double harmonic(int n) {
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return (1.0 / n) + (1.0 / harmonic(n - 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the recursion part should not include *1/harmonic(n-1)*
it should be

```
   public static double harmonic(int n)
  {
    double harm = 0.0;
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1.0;
    }
    else {
        harm = harm + (1.0 / n) +  harmonic(n - 1);
    }
    return harm;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Created by hrishikesh.mishra on 04/01/16.
 *
 * Describe a recursive algorithm
 * for computing the nth Harmonic number,
 * defined as Hn = ∑ n k=1 1/k.
 *
 */
public class HarmonicNumber {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Sum up to 1: "  + sum(1));
        System.out.println("Sum up to 2: "  + sum(2));
        System.out.println("Sum up to 3: "  + sum(3));
        System.out.println("Sum up to 4: "  + sum(4));
    }


    /**
     * Summation with recursive method.
     * @param n
     * @return
     */
    public static double sum(int n){
        if(n <= 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return ((double) 1/n) + sum(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation of the harmonic number recursion.

```
double harmonic(int n){

    if(n == 1)return 1;
    else return 1.0 / n + harmonic(n - 1);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static double harmonic(int n)
   {
      if (n==1)
      return 1/n;
      else return 1/n + harmonic(n-1);
   }
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your code-only answer.

Comment: The base case is just `return 1;` since `n == 1` and you do `1/n`.