# Java program to add 1+1/2+1/3.. with user inputting the range

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class Brain {

static int range;

double calculate() {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int n = 1; n <= Brain.range; n++) {

        sum = sum + (double) (1 / n);

    }

    return sum;

}
```

}

I am always getting the return as 1.0. I tried to understand it here, but no help : [Harmonic sequence recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904284/harmonic-sequence-recursion)

Comment: Integer division.  Do the cast BEFORE the division, not after.

Comment: i didn't see any recursion here

Comment: that is, do `sum = sum + ((double) 1 / n);` or just `sum = sum + (1.0 / n);`