# Harmonic recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am currently working on a harmonic sequence problem recursively and I keep getting an error message that says "at LinearRecursion.harmonicSum(LinearRecursion.java:59)"
this is my code for the harmonic problem. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
public static double harmonicSum(int n) {
        if(n == 1)
        {
            return 1.0;
        }
        else
        {
            return (1.0 / n) + harmonicSum(n - 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You did not post the error message but sounds like dividing by zero

Comment: when I run that code it just says "at LinearRecursion.harmonicSum(LinearRecursion.java:59)"

Comment: Any time you call that method you will have a divide by zero exception.  Your if statement will always evaluate to false because you are comparing a floating point number to an integer.  Try using `<=` instead of `==`.

Comment: Also your provided error message only says which line has the error but not the error itself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Harmonic sequence recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12904284/harmonic-sequence-recursion)

Comment: thank you I was able to figure it out ```

Comment: i used 0 as my base case and had it return 0 and the program worked